# How to make this kind of effect in iOS, blur effect it is increasing leaner to lower side

Tags: ios, ios7

I am searched for this, but i didn't found the exact solution for my problem, all the answer for making blur effect shows making the blur effect on entire frame but i want the blur effect something look like below image

[image]

in the image the blur effect is at the bottom that to, it is increasing leaner to lower side

can any one know how to do this, any ideas or sample code for this ... :)

Comment: Use Gradient color with alpha components.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi can u post some sample code how to achieve this ...?

Comment: Simple way would be create a image and apply over it as at end you have to overlay that view with some other view. Will save you from code of line's. Else you could go for above mentioned method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CAGradientLayer`

```
UIColor *theColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:146.0/255.0 green:146.0/255.0 blue:146.0/255.0 alpha:1];

CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

CGRect gradientLayerFrame = theView.frame;
gradientLayerFrame.origin.x = 0;
gradientLayerFrame.origin.y = 0;
gradientLayer.frame = gradientLayerFrame;

//build the colors array for the gradient
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   (id)[theColor CGColor],
                   (id)[[theColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9f] CGColor],
                   (id)[[theColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6f] CGColor],
                   (id)[[theColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4f] CGColor],
                   (id)[[theColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3f] CGColor],
                   (id)[[theColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1f] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
                   nil];

gradientLayer.colors = colors;

[yourView.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

swift version of this code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626260/how-do-you-create-the-blur-colour-effect-used-in-the-ios-9-music-app/37626552#37626552)

Comment: thnx i will try it ... :)

Comment: what is `theColor` that u are used in the array

Comment: theColor is instance of `UIColor`