# Transparency and Gradient in imageView

Tags: ios, transparency, gradient

How can I make imageView with half-transparansed bottom side

Simply I want have imageView with gradient. Gradient from image to white transparency

Comment: The image needs to have an alpha channel. You can manipulate the alpha channel to get the gradient you want.

Comment: this  might helps u, it uses gradient to make white transparent  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262602/how-to-make-this-kind-of-blur-effect-in-ios-blur-effect-it-is-increasing-leaner