# How do you create the blur/colour effect used in the iOS 9 music app?

Tags: ios, swift

How would you implement the blur/colour effect (I'm not too sure what it is, to be honest) seen in the link below?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: look at this answer it is in  obj-c , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262602/how-to-make-this-kind-of-effect-in-ios-blur-effect-it-is-increasing-leaner-to-l, it is  gradient layer

Comment: @Shan, thanks! I'll try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok any way i am posting the swift version of the linked answer, similar to your requirement.

u can do like below, just create a gradient layer with the color's u want to spread across the gradient layer finally set the gradient later to image view, for example

```
@IBOutlet weak var aImageView: UIImageView!
var theColor: UIColor?
var gradientLayer:CAGradientLayer?
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 self.theColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 146.0/255.0, green: 146.0/255.0, blue: 146.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
 self.gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
 self.gradientLayer?.frame = self.aImageView.frame
 let array: [AnyObject] = [(theColor?.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.1))!.CGColor,
 (theColor?.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.12))!.CGColor,(theColor?.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.13))!.CGColor,
 (theColor?.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.74))!.CGColor,
 (theColor?.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.82))!.CGColor,
 (theColor?.colorWithAlphaComponent(1.0))!.CGColor]
 gradientLayer?.colors = array;
    aImageView.layer .addSublayer(gradientLayer!);
}
```

just try put in sample project, the result will be like below

[image]